# How to find the next unbalanced brace?

Tags: regex, perl, recursion

The regex below captures everything up to the last balanced `}`.

Now, what regex would be able to capture everything up to the next **unbalanced** `}`?  In other words, how can I can get `... {three {four}} five}` from `$str` instead of just `... {three {four}}`?

```
my $str = "one two {three {four}} five} six";

if ( $str =~ /
              (
                .*?
                {
                  (?> [^{}] | (?-1) )+
                }
              )
            /sx
   )
   {
     print "$1\n";
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to match

```
[noncurlies [block noncurlies [...]]] "}"
```

where a `block` is

```
"{" [noncurlies [block noncurlies [...]]] "}"
```

As a grammar:

```
start    : text "}"
text     : noncurly* ( block noncurly* )*
block    : "{" text "}"
noncurly : /[^{}]/
```

As a regex (5.10+):

```
/
   ^
   (
      (
         [^{}]*
         (?:
             \{ (?-1) \}
             [^{}]*
         )*
      )
      \}
   )
/x
```

As a regex (5.10+):

```
/
   ^ ( (?&TEXT) \} )

   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<TEXT>   [^{}]* (?: (?&BLOCK) [^{}]* )*   )
      (?<BLOCK>  \{ (?&TEXT) \}                   )
   )
/x
```

Comment: It works. It will take me some time to understand the innermost trick, though.

Comment: Just think of `(?-1)` as `text` in the grammar.

Comment: Added alternate regex solution

Comment: May I edit your answer to add a disjunct, `(?<=\\)[{}]`, to allow for escaped curly brackets?

Comment: That's true. Do you know how to improve it?